# Same XMLHttpRequest instance for redirect?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

If an ajax request returns a 302, will the redirect happen on the same XMLHttpRequest instance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the browser will handle the redirect and you will get the response from the final resource the browser ended up on. If the 302 redirect is to a different domain than the one your XHR originated from, you will still have to enable CORS headers on that server.